# Java: adding double arrays to a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, double

I am trying to create a list of arrays. These arrays contain doubles. When I use .add() I get this error: no suitable method found for add(double[])
method.java.util.List.add(int,java.lang.Double[]) is not applicable

Here is a simplification of my code:

```
List<Double[]> allTris = new ArrayList<Double[]>();

List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
tempList.add("0.0");
tempList.add("1.0");
tempList.add("2.0");

double[] tri = new double[tempList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
    tri[i] = Double.parseDouble(tempList.get(i));
}
allTris.add(tri);  //here is where my error is happening
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
List<Double[]> allTris = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

to

```
List<double[]> allTris = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

`Double` (a class) is a wrapper around `double` (a primitive). They two different things.